# Magento2.2.4 - Invalid form key while save product

Tags: magento2.2.4, form-key, product-edit

I have Magento 2.2.4.

I have tried increasing `max_input_vars` in `php.ini` file.

I have cleared `var/cache`, browser cache, removed domain cookies.

Still, get the error when trying to edit an existing product.
But, I can create new products without any issue.

Error: Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page.

Comment: Working or not?

Comment: Not working but thanks for the efforts

Comment: Execute `sudo service apache2 restart` this or not?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is occurred after adding more custom options in the product because php.ini file not allowed to add more custom option.

So, required to change default settings of php.ini file.

Now, Edit your `php.ini` file.

If php version 7.1 then,

> **/etc/php/7.1/apache2/php.ini**

If php version 7.0 then,

> **/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini**

Uncomment this value and update this all value in php.ini,

```
max_input_vars = 200000
max_input_time = 600
max_execution_time = 3600
```

Now Restart Apache 2 web server, and check it.

> sudo service apache2 restart

Comment: happens to me periodically at magento upgrade as it wipes my local settings